# Should not "unknown-host" be changed to "unknown-host-exception", if it worth keeping it?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

There are 11 questions tagged [unknown-host](/questions/tagged/unknown-host) that are all about an exception raised at runtime.

Does it make sense to have it? It seems that it is grouping questions for which the code has raised that exception. Does it add anything to the question? Is there an expert about that exception that is going to answer all those answers?

If it is worth keeping it, the tag should probably renamed [unknown-host-exception](/questions/tagged/unknown-host-exception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm all for burning it!

```
88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
88888888888?    8    ~8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
88888888D.      MMM     I8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
8888888 MMM.   =MM        ?88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
88888,   MMM.  M.    M     .8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
8888~       =MMMMMMMMMMMM    888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
8888     +NMMMMMMMMMMMMMM     Z8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888     MMMMMMMMM7   MMMM       888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888     MMMMM.OMMMM              88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888     MMMM     MMMM,            O888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888      ZMM        MMM             88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888        MM       .MMM             8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888Z              ..DMMM              888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
8888           7 , MMMM                ,8888888888888888888888888888888888888888
88888         MMIMMMMM                   888888888888888888888888888888888888888
888888,          , .                      88888888888888888888888888888888888888
88888888        .                          :888888888888888888888888888888888888
8888888888.     :                $           88888888888888888888888888888888888
88888888888888 .                 Z            8888888888888888888888888888888888
8888888888888888888             $M             ~8888888888888888M888888888888888
8888888888888888888888Z        MMMM              888888888888888M888888888888888
88888888888888888888888888Z    MMMM.             .8888888888888MM888888888888888
888888888888888888888888888888MMMMMM   MMMM       MMMMM88888888MMM8888888MMM8888
888888888888888888888888888888MM,MMM   MMMM       MMMMM8888888MMMM88888MMMMM8888
888888888888888888888888888888MM M~M88MMMMMM.     MMMMM88MMMM8MMMMM8888MMMMM8888
888888888888888888888888888888MMMMMM88MMMMMMM     MMMMMD8MMMM8MMMM888DMMMMMM8888
888888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM,  MMMMM 7MMMM8MMMM888DMMMMMM8888
888888888888888888888888888888MMMM~MMMMMMMMMMMM88DMMMMM  MMMM8MMMM88MMMMMMMMMM88
888888888888888888888888888888MM MMMMMM MMMMMMM88MMMMMMMMMMMM8MMMM88MMMMMMMMMMDD
888888888888888888888888888888MM.MMMMMM MMMM,MM88MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM88MMMMMMMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMDMMMMMMMMMMMM88MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM88MMMMMMMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMM M+MMMM MMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMM?MMMMMM+MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM M MMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMDOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM M M,MMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMMMMMMM=MOM$MMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
888888888888888888888888888MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
                                                                 GlassGiant.com
```

**Edit:** To add something constructive, I don't think that that tag adds anything of value, as do none such tags. Exceptions are only symptoms and should not have there own tags, because tags should be what the question is about, not what it...arm...produces(?).

Comment: It took me a while, to understand the picture. `:)`